# Linq to XML to get one-to-many Element Name and Attribute name/value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<manager firstName="Dat" lastName="Bossman">
   <employee firstName="Jonathan" lastName="Smith" preferredName="Jon" />
   <employee christianName="Jane" lastName="Doe" />
   <employee lastName="Jones" firstInitial="A" middleName="J" />
</manager>
```

I'd like to return a collection/list of all element-name/attribute-name/attribute-value combiniations where the attribute name is in { "firstName", "preferredName", "christianName", "firstInitial", "middleName" }

Given the above XML, I'd have a list that looks like this:

```
elementName  attributeName  attributeValue
============ ============== ===============
manager      firstName      Dat
employee     firstName      Jonathan
employee     preferredName  Jon
employee     christianName  Jane
employee     firstInitial   A
employee     middleName     J
```

I've got some LINQ, below, that is returning the correct elements, but I'm unsure how to convert that into the a collection/list that helps me get the properties above.

```
List<string> desiredAttributes = new List<string>();
desiredAttributes.AddRange(new string[] { "firstName", "preferredName", "christianName", "firstInitial", "middleName" });

XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);

IEnumerable<XElement> theResults = document.Descendants()
    .Where(el => el.Attributes().Any(att => desiredAttributes.Contains(att.Name.LocalName)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to return all the desired attributes from each element, and then project the result into data structure that is convenient for you :

```
var theResults = document.Descendants()
    //select all the desired attributes
    .SelectMany(el => el.Attributes().Where(att => desiredAttributes.Contains(att.Name.LocalName)))
    //projet the result into your data structure of choice (class, array, tuple, etc.)
    .Select(att => Tuple.Create(att.Parent.Name.LocalName, att.Name.LocalName, att.Value));

foreach(var result in theResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjAYpv)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
(manager, firstName, Dat)
(employee, firstName, Jonathan)
(employee, preferredName, Jon)
(employee, christianName, Jane)
(employee, firstInitial, A)
(employee, middleName, J)
```

Comment: Using `Parent` to look back up the tree... I'd been too busy thinking about it the other way around. Thanks.